# How to test a React asynchronous custom hook that returns a boolean when an API call is resolved/rejected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs

I have a custom React hook as follows:

```
export function useValidPolicyReference({
  token,
  tenant,
  policyReference,
}: UseValidPolicyReferenceProps): Record<string, boolean> {
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = React.useState<boolean>(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchOnMount(): Promise<void> {
      try {
        await getPolicyByReference({
          policyReference: policyReference as string,
          tenant,
          token,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        setIsValid(false);
      }
    }
    if (tenant !== '' && policyReference !== null && token !== '') {
      fetchOnMount();
    }
  }, [policyReference, tenant, token]);

  return {
    isValidPolicyReference: isValid,
  };
```

I want to test that `isValidPolicyReference` will return true when `getPolicyByReference`  does not throw and false when it does.

My test for the true case is as follows:

```
  test('should be truthy if the policy reference is valid', () => {
    (getPolicyByReference as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve(true)
    );
    const {
      result: { current },
      waitForNextUpdate,
    } = render();

    expect(current.isValidPolicyReference).toBeTruthy();

    waitForNextUpdate();

    expect(getPolicyByReference).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      token,
      tenant,
      policyReference,
    });
    expect(current.isValidPolicyReference).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Which passes but the test for the false case does not:

```
  test('should be falsy if the policy reference is invalid', () => {
    (getPolicyByReference as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.reject(new Error('policy reference error'))
    );
    const {
      result: { current },
      waitForNextUpdate,
    } = render();

    expect(current.isValidPolicyReference).toBeTruthy();

    waitForNextUpdate();

    expect(current.isValidPolicyReference).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

It fails on two counts:

1. isValidPolicyReference never returns as false
2. There is also a `console.error` logged at this line `setIsValid(false);` where `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.`

I am not sure how to get `getPolicyByReference` to throw in Jest so that the hook will return the false value.

What am I not doing correctly?  Should I be wrapping my test cases in `async` `await`?  Should I mock `axios.get` instead of `getPolicyByReference`?

Answer (score 0):

> There is also a console.error logged at this line setIsValid(false); where Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

I think the issue is you are trying to test the hook alone with jest, when hooks can only be called from whithin components.

The [react testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) has really nice helpers to simplify testing hooks, [this](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-test-custom-react-hooks) article is quite informative on the matter.